# Batching a bash array by an arbitrary number and store results in another array

Tags: arrays, bash

Suppose you did something simple like this in a BASH shell script:

```
folders=$(find "$1" -type d)
```

Against the root of a volume with 100,000s of thousands of folders and you want to perform some form of operation against them but in a batch fashion.

Is it possible, without enumerating with lots of code, to batch an array into an array of arrays, each consisting of 10 - or whatever - or in the last array maybe less?

Thanks,
Lee

**EDIT** for Cyrus

```
folders=('/Volume/Data/1'. '/Volumes/Data/1', '/Volumes/Data/1/A', 'Volumes/Data/1/B', '/Volumes/Data/1/C')
```

Batched version based on a batch site if twi (syntax could be totally incorrect and not supported, I'm a total BASH noob):

```
foldersBatched=(('/Volume/Data/1', '/Volumes/Data1/1'), ('/Volumes/Data/1/A', 'Volumes/Data/1/B'), ('/Volumes/Data/1/C'))
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: First, you shouldn't do `folders=$(find "$1" -type d)` as this variable is unusable (in case of filenames with newlines). There's very likely a much better way to proceed. What do you want to do with these directories?

Comment: Please would you explain further @gniourf-gniourf since I'm dealing with directories not filenames.   Thanks.

Comment: Ok @Cyrus... lets base the batch size on 2 for simplicity (laziness)

Comment: When I say filename I mean filename or directory name or device name or link name, etc. Now you should know that Bash _does not_ support arrays of arrays. What are you trying to _do_ with these directories?

Answer (score 0):

`bash` does not support multidimensional arrays.

Comment: `for i in $(find …)` is broken in case of filename with spaces or glob characters!

Comment: Well, if your only purpose it to spread bad practices and broken code, you'd better leave SO. But how about you learn from us? I actually told you _why_ your code is broken (I'm not harassing, rather I'm explaining). Now _This is common code in nearly every operating system_ well… I hope it's not, otherwise nearly every operating system is broken `:)`. [Here's a good link that explains why you shouldn't parse `ls`—and it also mentions why `for i in $(find …)` is bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thanks for the link @gniourf_gniourf.  The purpose of this is to move a  very large number of files and folders (Terabytes of data) from my local storage to the cloud via ExpanDrive (mounts a cloud service as a drive).   The problem being ExpanDrive caches the transfer on the OS drive and brought the whole system down by leaving just 1.24GB  free on that drive.  Despite having symmetric Gigabit it couldn't move the files fast enough.  So my idea is to send batches to the cloud, keep checknig/sleeping until the batch has been uploaded (i.e. cache folder is empty) and then send the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

folders=$(find $1 -type d)

#associative memory
typeset -A Tab 
#max col
iMaxCol=10

iLg=0
iCol=0
for fold in ${folders}
do
 Tab[${iLg}_${iCol}]=${fold}
 iCol=$(( iCol + 1 ))
 if [ ${iCol} -eq ${iMaxCol} ] ; then
   iLg=$(( iLg + 1 ))
   iCol=0
 fi
done

#Like Tab[0][0] 
echo ${Tab[0_0]}
#Like Tab[0][9] 
echo ${Tab[0_9]}
#Like Tab[1][5] 
echo ${Tab[1_5]}
```